# Store the counts for a specific value in a column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have a dataframe with two columns as `SESSION` and `PRICE_POINT`.

`SESSION` is a category variable (values with various ip sessions)

`PRICE_POINT` has two values such as 'high', 'low'

I am running the following:

```
n = pd.value_counts(df['price_point'].values, sort=False)
```

My output is,

```
high    30204
low     62978
dtype: int64
```

What I need is, I want to get the count of "high" and "low" from the column "price_point" separately and store that values as n = 30204 and m = 62978.

Any ideas?

Comment: IIUC isn't this just `high = n.index['high']` and `low = n.index['low']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
n = df.price_point.value_counts().high
m = df.price_point.value_counts().low

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'price':['high', 'high', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low']})
df.price.value_counts().high

2
```

or, in two steps:

```
counts = df.price_point.value_counts()
n = counts.high
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC then you just index the series using the values, example:

```
In [94]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['high','high','low','low','low','low']})
df['col1'].value_counts()

Out[94]:
low     4
high    2
Name: col1, dtype: int64

In [96]:
counts.index

Out[96]:
Index(['low', 'high'], dtype='object')

In [97]:    
counts = df['col1'].value_counts()
print('high: ', counts['high'], 'low: ', counts['low'])

high:  2 low:  4
```